# PyPDF2 returns negative dimension

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I use PyPDF2 to get pdf file pages` dimension but it return negative number for some pdfs. Why?
Here is an [example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18MWWR_uIPrRkWykVccDh9ehkegU9Kwsv), starting from second page, the real height is negative.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

input_file = PdfFileReader(open('file.pdf', "rb"))
for i in range(input_file.getNumPages()):
    page = input_file.getPage(i)
    real_width, real_height = page.mediaBox.getWidth(), 
page.mediaBox.getHeight()
    print(real_width, real_height)
```

The real height in some cases is negative, how can this happen?

Comment: We can't replicate this without an example file, or at least a description of the 'types' of PDF where this occurs.

Comment: I have added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's the height of the page in the metadata in the file

```
MediaBox [0 0 792 -612]
```

You'd have to ask whomever generated the file how they've managed that!  You could probably just invert it.

Comment: A more scalable approach is to realize height is a *difference*, rather than an absolute value. `abs(top - bottom)` should work for all possible numbers. In this case, the PDF producer probably was irked by its negative y-axis and so inverted the whole lot.

Comment: @usr2564301 sounds like a bug report for the library is in order.  Although you can directly access the mediabox values,  I'd edit my answer by I've flagged this question for closure as 'Solved in a way not helpful to other people'

Comment: Your first question was a perfect candidate for SO, it just happened to be an easy answer... now you're just pasted some code in it's no longer really a question..